# How to move my content down? The section keeps overlapping

Tags: html, css

Could I please have some help, I am fairly new. I'm trying to move the second section tag down the page but it keeps overlapping with the other section.

I'm trying to make it in its own container without the body background overlapping it. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
body {
 background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/31/23/08/water-3279564_1280.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 text-align: center;
}

h1 {
 padding-top: 20%;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
}

h6 {
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#content {
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/oil.css">

    <title>Oil Rig</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<section>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div id="content">
     <h1>Welcome to Oil Rig Company</h1>
     <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h6>
     <button class="btn btn-warning">About Us</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>

<section class="about" id="about">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/13/14/34/oil-platform-32639_1280.png">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <h3>Our Mission</h3>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing anim id est laborum.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don’t see any overlapping between those two sections, they are just one below the other. Inspecting them in browser dev tools further proves that. Unclear therefor what you’re asking.

Comment: How do I move the second section basically on its own page like down. Without the background image all over it?